# Swift and Objective-C++ Interoperability

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, interop, objective-c++

I have a C++ API with which I need to interact inside a Swift project. I know I [cannot interact with C++ from Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) directly, but I know I can do this through an Objective-C wrapper. That much is clear.

However, I cannot find anywhere if Swift and Objective-C++ can interop with each other. I'd like to write the C++ wrapper in Objective-C++, if possible, given the API's complexity. Does anyone know if Objective-C++ and Swift can interop?

Answer (score 1):

Swift and objective-c++ cannot interact. As soon as there is c++ code in the objective-c bridge header that the swift compiler use, you will get a compile error.
You need to completely hide your c++ code behind a pure c or pure objective-c API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why they wouldn't, as Objective-C++ is fundamentally Objective-C.  You might have to (you want to in any case) hide the C++ object pointers as private properties in the implementation file, but other than that there shouldn't be any issues.

Obviously you'll have to completely extract/abstract the C++ objects.